# ValueError: Duplicated level name: "rec_id", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0

Tags: python, record-linkage

While I implemented this code example on [record linkage](http://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/link_two_dataframes.html) python documentation:

```
import recordlinkage
from recordlinkage.datasets import load_febrl4

dfA, dfB = load_febrl4()

# Indexation step
indexer = recordlinkage.BlockIndex(on='given_name')
pairs = indexer.index(dfA, dfB)

# Comparison step
compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare()

compare_cl.exact('given_name', 'given_name', label='given_name')
compare_cl.string('surname', 'surname', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='surname')
compare_cl.exact('date_of_birth', 'date_of_birth', label='date_of_birth')
compare_cl.exact('suburb', 'suburb', label='suburb')
compare_cl.exact('state', 'state', label='state')
compare_cl.string('address_1', 'address_1', threshold=0.85, label='address_1')

features = compare_cl.compute(pairs, dfA, dfB)

# Classification step
matches = features[features.sum(axis=1) > 3]
print(len(matches))
```

I encounter the following error:

```
Error: ValueError: Duplicated level name: "rec_id", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.
```

Comment: The code run without an error and display the desired output on Jupyter

Comment: @NipunSampath do you have a clue of what might be responsible for the error for someone not using Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Thanks, it worked also for me on the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I think it has some thing to do with the version. Not sure though

Answer (score 0):

(In Eclipse or Visual Studio code)  *Python record linkage* is an algorithm; hence, it is worth implementing while using the [Template design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Also, ensure **python2** upgrade before installing the requirements in the [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/):

**Upgrade python2**

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Thereafter

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

With this, the **ValueError** vanished.